# policy returns This action is unauthorized no matter what

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, policy

i am just trying to show a company to anyone who ants to see it
authServiceProvider:

```
        Company::class => CompanyPolicy::class ,
'App\Models\Company' => 'App\Policies\CompanyPolicy',
```

companyPolicy

```
 public function view( Company $company)
{

    return true ;
}
```

companyController

```
 public function __construct(CompanyRepository $companies)
{
    $this->companies = $companies;
}


public function show(Company $company)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $company);

    return $this->companyRepository->show($company);
}
```

route to controller:

```
Route::apiResource('companies', 'CompanyController');
```

it always return This action is unauthorized. why?

Comment: the first argument to policy methods and abilities is an `Authenticatable` (User)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of `Company::class => CompanyPolicy::class,` is redundant in your `AuthServiceProvier` and you have to remove it.

let me bring an example:

assume we have a model named `SomeModel` and have registered its policy. the policy has the method of `view` which check current user is able to call show method.

For Guard of `api` you may create a `trait` like below:

```
trait ApiTrait
{
    /**
     * Authorize a given action for the current user.
     *
     * @param  mixed $ability
     * @param  mixed|array $arguments
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function authorizeApi($ability, $arguments)
    {
        if (!request()->user('api')->can($ability, $arguments)) {
            abort(403, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
    }
}
```

then in your controller use it:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    use ApiTrait;

    public function show(SomeModel $something)
    {
        $this->authorize('view', $something);

        return 'it workes';
    }
}
```

pay attention you should protect your route with middleware of `auth:api` or else you will get error code 500 when calling the `can` method in `ApiTrait`.